# How Do I override a Javascript Method In Typescript Code?

Tags: typescript, draw2d-js

I am using draw2d-js, wherein I need the `onMouseEnter()` functionality.
The [docs](https://www.draw2d.org/draw2d_touch/jsdoc_6/#!/api/draw2d.shape.basic.PolyLine-method-onMouseEnter) suggest that I override the `onMouseEnter`:

```js
  /**
     * @method
     * Callback method for the mouse enter event. Usefull for mouse hover-effects.
     * Override this method for your own effects. Don't call them manually.
     *
     * @template
     **/
    onMouseEnter: function()
    {
    },
```

I have tried:
(file: on_mouse_enter.ts):

```
const draw2d = require('draw2d');

export class CustomEdge extends draw2d.Figure {
  override onMouseEnter(): void {
    console.log('Mouse Entered');
  }
}
```

However, I get the error:

```bash
Error: src/library/onMouseEnter.ts:7:12 - error TS4113: This member cannot have an 'override' modifier because it is not declared in the base class 'any'.

7   override onMouseEnter(): void {
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I want to override *only* one method from the `draw2s.Figure` class: the `onMouseEnter()` method.

Comment: Drop the `override` keyword in this case. `override` is for functions for which the override signature can be statically verified, and your parent function doesn't have a declared type. If you're feeling ambitious, you can write a `.d.ts` file to well-type `draw2d`, but that's probably overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, @Silvio Mayolo.

The final solution looks like this:

```
// client, the caller
  let _customEdge = new CustomEdge();
  _customEdge.onMouseEnter(_con);
```

The implementation of `onMouseEnter` looks like so:

```
const draw2d = require('draw2d');

export class CustomEdge extends draw2d.Figure {
  onMouseEnter(_con: any): void {
    console.log('Mouse Entered');
    //_con.set
  }
```

The function works correctly when mouse enters the designated area on the screen.

Comment: Hi, @O hoo O, Welcome! Thanks to share your solution with the community. Please, could you check your question as resolved? Congrats!